# Printing a method from the main method

Tags: java, printing

I'm fairly new to `java` and I am wondering how I can print the `Boxvolume` variable from my `volume` method.

I do understand that I need to make `Boxvolume` a global variable. So if anyone can help me with that it would be very much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Box a = new Box(20, 30, 40);

    ArrayList<Box> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
    boxes.add(a);

    for (Box bx : boxes) {
        bx.print();
    }

    double V = volume(Boxvolume);
    System.out.println(V);
}

class Box {
    int width;
    int height;
    int depth;

    public Box(int w, int h, int d) {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.depth = d;
    }

    public double volume(double BoxV) {
        int Boxvolume = width * height * depth;
        return Boxvolume;
    }

    public double price(double BV) {
        double Boxprice = volume(BV) * 5;
        return Boxprice;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.width);
        System.out.println(this.height);
        System.out.println(this.depth);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: that actually leads into another question i have. i want to use the Boxvolume variable within my price method. Have i done it correctly?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're even trying to do or why.  On which instance of `Box` do you want to call the `.volume()` method?  What value do you want to pass to that method?

Comment: . I want to pass the value for Boxvolume to be used in the price method because i need its part of an equation i need to use to calcuate the price

Comment: The `.volume()` method doesn't even use the value that you pass it, so why does it need that value?

Comment: Take care of Java naming conventions. varable names should start with lower case character

Comment: it needs the volume for an equation. The lab question states "add a price method to your box Class It will return a double price. It will need to call your volume method"

Comment: @MichaelCheng: Right, but look at your `.volume()` method.  At *just* that method.  What does that method do?  Why does it need a parameter?  If it doesn't need the parameter, remove the parameter.  Follow the ripple effect of doing that and see how the code becomes simpler.  Simple is good.

Comment: The volume method calculates the volume of a box

Comment: @MichaelCheng: Yes it does.  So, once again, why does that method need a parameter?  What do you need that `BoxV` value for in that method?  (Hint: You don't need it.)

Comment: Yes i realize that now, i asked my mate and he told me i dont need paramaters as ive already declared them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close to being right - for a beginner anyway :)

There just seems to be a slight conceptual misunderstanding in the way you're approaching the solution. I apologise if I'm being overly simplistic, or assuming that you know less than you do, but it seems better to over-explain than under-explain.

First of all the `main()` method. As it's `static`, that means there's only one of it - you can think of it like the big boss, controlling what's going on in your small application.

That `main()` method (the boss) creates a `Box`, that's a single instance of a 'thing'. The boss knows about it, and refers to his box as `a`. He adds that box to a collection, which, for now, only has box `a` in it, but could, in future, have many boxes. I'm sure you get all this so far, just mentioning it as background.

The `Box` class can do a few things. It knows the `width`, `height` and `depth` of itself, and it knows how to calculate the `volume` and the `price` based on those attributes. It can also `print` a representation of itself on to the system console.

In your `main` method, after you create the box called `a` you want to ask that box what its volume is. To do that, you have to call the `volume` method **on the instance of the box that you're interested in**.

So, you're not just asking for any volume, you're asking for the volume of box `a`. You do this with the following syntax:

```
a.volume();
```

You don't need to pass anything into the `volume` method (so you should delete the `double BoxV` from the `volume` method, because the `volume` method is part of the `Box` itself, and therefore it already knows everything that `Box` knows - the `width`, `height` and `depth`, which is all it needs to be able to calculate the volume.

So, a few changes you need to make:

The `volume` method doesn't need to take any parameters, and should just be:

```
public double volume() {
  return width * height * depth;
}
```

(note that you also don't need to assign it to the `int Boxvolume` and can remove that variable - or leave it if you prefer, entirely up to you)

Once you've done that in your `main` method, you can get and print the volume of box `a` with:

```
double volume = a.volume();
System.out.println(volume);
```

If you wanted to print the volume of all the boxes in your list (which for now is just the one) you'd put the equivalent code within your `for` loop, like:

```
for (Box bx : boxes) {
  bx.print();
  double volume = bx.volume();
  System.out.println(volume);
}
```

Note that here we're calling `bx.volume()`, not `a.volume()`, because in this case we're interested in the volume of the box we're currently considering within the loop, not just box `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong at all. First you to call your volume method from instance variable which is `a.volume();`. Also you don't need a double parameter in your volume and price methods. Price method is already calls volume and you are not use BV parameter in volume.

So the correct version should be look like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Box a = new Box(20, 30, 40);

    ArrayList<Box> boxes = new ArrayList<>();

    boxes.add(a);

    for (Box bx : boxes) {
        bx.print();
        System.out.println(bx.volume());
    }    
}

class Box {

    int width;
    int height;
    int depth;


    public Box(int w, int h, int d) {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.depth = d;

    }

    public double volume() {

        int Boxvolume = width * height * depth;
        return Boxvolume;

    }

    public double price() {

        double Boxprice = volume() * 5;

        return Boxprice;
    }



    public void print() {

        System.out.println(this.width);
        System.out.println(this.height);
        System.out.println(this.depth);

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: May i ask why its Boxprice = volume()  * 5 and not Boxprice = Boxvolume() * 5

Comment: There is not any method named Boxvolume(). `Boxvolume` is a local variable of the `volume()` method. So you can not access another method's local variable outside of that method.

Answer (score 0):

You would be well advised to follow the Java naming conventions and remove unnecessary parameters.

This example gives your `Box` a `toString()` method for printing, removes dispensable parameters, gives variables names according to the Java naming conventions and uses the class methods `getVolume()` and `getPrice()` in other class methods. If you have `height`, `width` and `depth` as class attributes, you won't need additional ones for volume or price, just return the results using `height`, `width` and `depth` or a class method:

```
class Box {

    int width;
    int height;
    int depth;

    public Box(int w, int h, int d) {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.depth = d;
    }

    /*
     * - renamed the method
     * - removed the dispensable parameter
     */
    public double getVolume() {
        int Boxvolume = width * height * depth;
        return Boxvolume;
    }

    /*
     * - renamed the method
     * - removed the dispensable parameter
     */
    public double getPrice() {
        // use the getVolume() method
        double Boxprice = this.getVolume() * 5;
        return Boxprice;
    }

    public void print() {
        // just print the toString() method
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("Height: ");
        // here you take the class attributes
        sb.append(height);
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("Depth: ");
        sb.append(depth);
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("Width: ");
        sb.append(width);
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("Price: ");
        // here you just take your method
        sb.append(getPrice());
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("Volume: ");
        // so you do here
        sb.append(getVolume());
        sb.append("\n");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Then you can check the output in a class that has a `main` method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PasteClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box a = new Box(20, 30, 40);
        Box b = new Box(10, 20, 30);

        ArrayList<Box> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
        boxes.add(a);
        boxes.add(b);

        for (Box bx : boxes) {
            bx.print();
        }
    }
}
```